# Java 3D Box and Cylinder inconstency with parameters

Tags: java-3d

I have created a Box(1,1,1) and a cylinder (0.5,1) at the same scene. But when I look in the fig the size of the box is twice the size of the cylinder. Does box (1,1,1) means the length width and height of the cube?? When i draw a sphere or cone the measures are consistent with the cylinder?

Answer (score 0):

the javadoc of Box is a bit dubious. The constructor's parameters 'float xdim, float ydim, float zdim' are NOT width, height, and depth. A Box is centered at the origin (0, 0, 0). The three parameters define the upper corner on the positive axes X, Y, and Z. The corresponding lower corner is (-xdim, -ydim, -zdim) on the negative axes. So, the size of a Box is: width = xdim x 2, height = ydim x 2, and depth = zdim x 2.

August